# How to change Python default compiler to GCC?

Tags: python, gcc, theano

I have Windows 10 and Python 2.7 installed. When I run IDLE I find this:
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

I want the default compiler here to be MinGW's GCC (I already installed MinGW) becaue I cannot import Theano with the MSC compiler

I tried all the tutorials out there and every time I successfully install Theano but when I try to import it I get the error "Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:" and I get a huge list of errors. Btw, I don't have VS installed on my system

Comment: How did you try to install theano? Please detail your question. What were the problems you encountered?

Comment: I tried all the tutorials out there and every time I successfully install Theano but when I try to import it I get the error "Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:" and I get a huge list of errors.
Btw, I don't have VS installed on my system

Answer (score 2):

Edit Distutils config file C:\Python2.7\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg (Create the file if it already does not exist).

Add the following to the file:

> [build]
>
> compiler = mingw32

This should work.

Comment: Have you installed libpython? If not install it and see what happens. I assume the error message is too long to post here.

Comment: When you say it didn’t work, did you try actually reinstalling the package, or just checking what IDLE says when you open it? The compiler IDLE lists isn’t necessarily the same one that is used when installing packages.