# How to change Anaconda Python default compiler to a newer version GCC?

Tags: python, gcc

The version of gcc used by python is not updated. The question is a bit similar to this one but unfortunately the answers do not not help:

[How to change Python default compiler to GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189453/how-to-change-python-default-compiler-to-gcc)

I am using centOS 6.5 and installing anaconda 2.

Already changed the version for the default GCC using this way

```
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-3-toolchain
$ echo "scl enable devtoolset-3 bash">>~/.bash_profile
$ scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

and also changed the gcc in /usr/bin/gcc as linked to the new one in devtoolset-3

When I use

```
$ gcc -v
```

The information would be like

```
gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC)
```

however when I type python it still shows

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
```

Comment: If the python executable is coming with anaconda, the python exec then build by continuum.io when it was released (Dec-20-2016). The gcc version showed there then depends on whatever toolchain continuum.io had used during that time. It has nothing to do with the local gcc tool chain.

Comment: Same issue with me. Unable to use Tensorflow cause of old gcc toolchain

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, the Python interpreter is compiled by Anaconda, and will always show the gcc version it was compiled with. What compiler you install in the operating system has no impact.

Anaconda provides its compilers as separate packages, which you can install and use. The `gcc` package is from an old toolchain though. With the [new compiler toolchain](https://www.anaconda.com/utilizing-the-new-compilers-in-anaconda-distribution-5/), the name of the compiler and related tools are longer and include the architecture for which the compiler works.

If you want other packages to use the compilers from Anaconda, you might have to set environment variables, depending on how the other packages build/install themselves. I don't think there is a generic solution for this. Whenever you can, you should be using packages from Anaconda rather than PyPI, because the former are pre-compiled with suitable compilers.