# mingw-w64 is not used for compiling

Tags: python, c, windows, docker

I am trying to use mingw-w64 to compile c module which is used inside a python package.

So, in my docker file I do the following:

```
# Change the default shell to PowerShell:
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

# Install Chocolatey, 7-Zip command-line version, and MinGW-w64
---------
---------

# Set MinGW-w64 as the default compiler for Python
ENV CC c:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
ENV CXX c:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe


# build wheel 
RUN python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

but when I control the docker log I see that minnow is not used at all

```
C:\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\tools\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\tools\miniconda3\include -IC:\tools\miniconda3\include -IC:\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include -IC:\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include -IC:\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /TcscDetectors.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\myfun.obj -m64
```

Any hints on how to set it correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189453/how-to-change-python-default-compiler-to-gcc

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks for your reply. 
I get now a different error

```
353  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 283, in __init__
354    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
355  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 127, in __init__
356    if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
357TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```